# An alternative for "eog" that I can use by "system(" ")" command?

Tags: imagemagick, image-viewers

I am using `eog` inside my c++ code for showing some images. But unfortunately it has borders when I use it on raspberrypi. I tried it by this command:

```
    system("eog --fullscreen --disable-gallery --single-window 1.jpg &");
```

It's strange because it has no borders when I try it on my laptop!
By the way, I am looking for a good and lightweight alternative that I can use it by `system()` function inside my code. Maybe it worked with no borders on raspberryPi.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://superuser.com/questions/1277520/an-alternative-for-eog-that-i-can-use-by-system-command https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47631/an-alternative-for-eog-that-i-can-use-by-system-command https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411205/why-eog-cant-show-my-image-in-fullscreen-are-there-any-better-choice

Comment: Delete my post here!

Comment: You can delete your own posts, no reason for anyone else to do it. Also no reason to delete since it's already closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/).

1. Install it with `sudo apt-get install feh`
2. Run it in the images folder with

   ```
   feh -x -q -D 5 -B black -g 1366x768 /path/to/images
   ```

You can consult its [man-page](https://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/) for all available options.